# django circular import solutions

Tags: python, django

Please help me. There is a Django project with circular import. Project's applications are connected only one side. But there are functions that use other models without params (for using in template) and that makes it impossible to move the function.

I have found two solutions:
First way is to import model inside function.
And another way it to move two models into one file.
Both solutions work without problem, but which one is better?

```
class InitialArticle(models.Model):
 by = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), null=True, on_delete = models.SET_NULL)
 category = models.ForeignKey(ArticleCategory, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 keywords = models.CharField(max_length = 110, unique = True)

def get_articles_of_initialarticle(self):
    from article.models import Article
    return Article.objects.filter(initial = self)
```

Please help me find a better way. Maybe there is another solution?

Comment: You're better off asking on https://codereview.stackexchange.com instead of here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add related_name in Article.initial like so:

```
class Article(...):
    initial = models.ForeignKey(to='InitialArticle', related_name='articles')
```

After that you can use it like so:

```
initial_article = InitialArticle.objects.filter(...).first()
initial_article.articles.all()  # return all articles which have foreign key to this article
```

Also in models.ForeignKey you can use string instead of importing the model like I have written

Or you can do it without adding related_name.

Default related name will be like so: article_set
And if you do not set related_name you can write like so:

```
initial_article = InitialArticle.objects.filter(...).first()
initial_article.article_set.all()  # return all articles which have foreign key to this article
```